# Remotely starting GlassFish v3 when server is down

Tags: java, linux, glassfish

I want to start GlassFish in case it crashes or so. Is this possible someway if I don't have administrator privilege on the Linux based server?

Any help would be appreciated!
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is your friend. Write a shell script that is invoked periodically by cron, that checks to see if the GlassFish process is running. (that is, assuming you have rights to actually restart the process.)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the necessary privileges you're not allowed to start it. That's the intention of these privileges.

You should ask the administrator to grant you all necessary privileges or to install a process monitor that automatically restarts the server in case it shuts down unexpectedly. [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) is a very lightweight example that comes to my mind.